# Which one is correct and optimized in sql?

Tags: sql-server, relational-theory, database-design

Imagine that I have three entities (`EntityA`, `EntityB`, `EntityC`) that can have some `images`. So there are two ways:

1. Make an `image` table for each entity. It means that `EntityA` has a `image` table named `AImages` and similarly for `EntityB` and `EntityC`.
   This method is more intelligent but has more tables.
2. Have an `image` table and another table name `EntityType` that goes between.

`EntityType` table has an `EntityTypeId` column and a `name` and has three records: `1,EntityA`, `2,EntityB`, `3,EntityC`.

Then in `image` table:

If I save a record for `EntityA` the record in `image` table would be this: `1,1,name`

First column is `ImageId`, second one is `EntityTypeId` and the third one is `image's filename`.

If I save a record for `EntityB` the record in `image` table would be this: `2,2,name`

And if I save a record for `EntityA` the record in `image` table would be this: `3,3,name`

In this method the number of tables would decrease but the queries would be longer.

Which one is optimised or any other way...

Comment: Do you expect to ever have more than 3 Entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the number of tables in your database.  SQL server can handle [a couple of billion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) object per DB.  Although there will be a theoretical performance overhead if *massive* numbers of objects exists, that will be nothing compared to badly-written, ill-indexed queries on poorly designed tables.

Holding data in the database is only one part of the story.  The other, more important part, is getting it out again.  Think through your use cases.  What queries will you be submitting to your schema?  Can you index efficiently to process each?  Can you write simple, clear SQL which someone can understand and fix at 3am, never having seen your code before?

So, for the actual question, I'd go for three separate tables.  Firstly, it's a cleaner design.  `ImageA` relates to `EntityA`; everyone can understand what's going on.  Just because two table have the same columns doesn't necessarily mean they are the same thing.  Second, with a combined table you can't put foreign key constraints on `ImageID` since it may refer to any one of three tables.  (It's not clear from your example but I'm assuming you plan to use an ID column in each of `EntityA, B and C`, and have the same value for corresponding `ImageID` values.)  Third, how will you index it?  Clustered by `EntityTypeID`, maybe three filtered indexes, perhaps even partition by `EntityTypeID`?  BANG! you've got three tables again, only buried under an extra layer of indirection.  Lastly, if an entity can have more than one image design 2 will require the name to be in the primary key, and that makes indexing inefficient.

One further question for your BAs - are the various images, according to the understanding of your application's user community, the same thing?  Outside of the system, in the real world, are they three classes of image created, processed, archived and destroyed in much the same way.  For example, if we are talking about X-rays photographs, they could be medical x-rays (`EntityA`), engineering inspection x-rays (`EntityB`) and fine art analysis x-rays (`EntityC`).  Three cases, but the same thing, produced, processed and stored the same way.  If so, I'd have one Image table, with its own `ImageID` independent of the `EntityX` tables' IDs and three intersection tables linking `EntityX` to `Image`.  The tables would be

```
EntityA(ID, OtherStuff)
Image(ImageID, Name, MoreColumns)
ImageA(EntityAID, ImageID)
ImageB(EntityBID, ImageID)
ImageC(EntityCID, ImageID)
```

If these images are very different things and not intimately related in actual use, say MP3 files, pdf documents and JPGs then, definitely, separate `ImageA`, `ImageB` and `ImageC` tables.

If you do plump for a single image table make sure you have both `ImageID` and `EntityTypeID` in the primary key.  With just `ImageID` you'll end up having to co-ordinate the primary keys of `EntityA`, `EntityB` and `EntityC` and that's no fun.